# Get Current Category for Home Page

Tags: magento-1.9

```
Mage::registry('current_category')->getId();
```

This is not working for homepage . This it returns null. for this in Home page. (Not home Category).

Comment: Yes because Home page is not a category page......your code will only works in category pages that are created from Admin panel